# apt link is not working in opera browser

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, opera, apturl

Opera web browser is not working with apt: links. Is there any solution for this problem? I downloaded this opera 32 bit deb from their website and my distro is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Go to *Settings* > *Preferences*

[image]

- Go to *Advanced* > *Programs*

[image]

- Click on *Add* and add the following entries.

[image]

- Click OK and you're done!

Note: If you are using a version of Ubuntu that doesn't include the software center by default, install it first with the command `sudo apt-get install software-center`