# Opera apt link on Lubuntu?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, opera

Does anyone know how to use apt links on Lubuntu with Opera? I've found tutorials that work on Opera Ubuntu and Firefox Lubuntu, but none for Opera Lubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: That's what I thought, but telling Opera to open APT links with /usr/bin/software-center (as mentioned here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/191467/apt-link-is-not-working-in-opera-browser) didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked that `/usr/bin/software-center` exists? It might have moved since then.

Comment: No, the file does not exist in the specified location. Where could it have been moved to, if it's anywhere at all? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: Note: Linked Q & A is now corrected to include this scenario making this a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Issue the command: sudo apt-get install software-center

Configure Opera the same way [the other tutorials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191467/apt-link-is-not-working-in-opera-browser) suggested and it worked fine.